# Fraction at the same height

Tags: fractions

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:pressure3}
\cfrac{P_2}{P_0} = \cfrac{C_2}{C_2 + S^*_2}\cdot\cfrac{C_1}{C_1+S^*_1+\cfrac{C_2 S^*_2}{C_2+S^*_2}}
\end{equation}
```

How can I bring the first denominator at the same height as the second denominator?

[image]

Comment: You don't want it, trust me. `;-)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(see FOLLOW UP below for a more general approach)

Here a `\vphantom` of the tall term, added to the first term, can help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:pressure3}
\cfrac{P_2}{P_0} = \cfrac{C_2}{C_2 + S^*_2\vphantom{\cfrac{S^*_2}{S^*_2}}}
  \cdot\cfrac{C_1}{C_1+S^*_1+\cfrac{C_2 S^*_2}{C_2+S^*_2}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**FOLLOW UP**

In response to David's comment, rather than over-exercising the `\vphantom` approach above, I introduce `\sfrac` which uses the values of `\topgap` and `\botgap` as baselineskips to the numerator and denominator, regardless of the height of those quantities.  It thus avoids the use of `\vphantom`s.

It would be intended to use on the first level of all terms of the fraction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\def\topgap{7pt}
\def\botgap{\topgap}
\newcommand\sfrac[2]{\def\stacktype{L}\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackunder[\botgap]{\stackon[\topgap]{\dfrac{\phantom{#1}}{\phantom{#2}}}{#1}}{#2}%
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\def\botgap{15pt}
\sfrac{P_2}{P_0} = \sfrac{C_2}{C_2 + S^*_2}
  \cdot\sfrac{C_1}{C_1+S^*_1+\cfrac{C_2 S^*_2}{C_2+S^*_2}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now *P₀* looks funny. This is going nowhere good.... ;)

Comment: @David See my follow-up.  It is less nowhere-good than the `\vphantom` approach.